# How do I add a title on top of a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have a list View that scrolls inside a container and has 7 tiles. I want to add the Title   'Settings' on top of the list view that must remain there even when the list view scrolls.
[image]

When I added it the list was scrolling but behind the title. This made it very hard for the list view items to be read. Is there a better way to add this title?

[image]

This is my code for the listView inside the container with rounded edges:

```
  Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 408.0, left: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 590,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(34)),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 10),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      primary: false,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 7,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        IconData icon;

                        if (index == 0) {
                          icon = Entypo.phone;
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          icon = Entypo.help;
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          icon = Entypo.email;
                        } else if (index == 3) {
                          icon = Entypo.star;
                        } else if (index == 4) {
                          icon = Entypo.share;
                        } else if (index == 5) {
                          icon = Entypo.info;
                        } else if (index == 6) {
                          icon = Entypo.log_out;
                        } else if (index == 7) {
                          icon = Entypo.log_out;
                        }

                        return new GestureDetector(
                          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                          onTap: () => {_onTileClicked(index)},
                          child: SettingsCard(
                            title: settingsAry[index]['title'],
                            description: settingsAry[index]['description'],
                            index: index,
                            iconData: icon,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          'Settings',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 23),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Use Positioned to align with the stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place them in a column: first the title, followed by an `Expanded` with the `ListView` as a child. This should do it:

```
  Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 408.0, left: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 590,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(34)),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          'Settings',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 23),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      primary: false,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 7,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        IconData icon;

                        if (index == 0) {
                          icon = Entypo.phone;
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          icon = Entypo.help;
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          icon = Entypo.email;
                        } else if (index == 3) {
                          icon = Entypo.star;
                        } else if (index == 4) {
                          icon = Entypo.share;
                        } else if (index == 5) {
                          icon = Entypo.info;
                        } else if (index == 6) {
                          icon = Entypo.log_out;
                        } else if (index == 7) {
                          icon = Entypo.log_out;
                        }

                        return new GestureDetector(
                          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                          onTap: () => {_onTileClicked(index)},
                          child: SettingsCard(
                            title: settingsAry[index]['title'],
                            description: settingsAry[index]['description'],
                            index: index,
                            iconData: icon,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

I replaced your `Padding` with an `Expanded` because it was easier to do. You can keep the `Padding` inside the `Expanded` if you like.